# Problem logging in with an old home account

Tags: home-directory, nfs, logging

I have just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and I am trying to use an old user home directory. 
My network is set up with a NIS server for authentication. I have installed nis package and configure the passwd, shadow and group files.

The home directory is mounted using NFS. The old user is unable to log in, the login screen just returns without logging in.

But if I create a new user in my NIS server, this user works just fine. I suppose it is an issue with the files of the old user, but I have already moved all the hidden files and folders to a ~/oldconfig/, and still no joy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the problem. It was related with user home directory permissions, it was set to "drwx------" and changing it to "drwxr-xr-x" works!!.